# Using Tycho behind a proxy that requires authentication

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, maven, tycho

I need to use the Tycho plug-in for Maven behind a firewall that requires authentication. The workaround here:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/TYCHO-279

Nearly works, I just need a way of providing a username and password.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like the issue is in the process of being patched. In the meantime we worked around it by setting up a proxy that doesn't require authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password
```

Comment: I had tried that and it didn't work unfortunately. I think a Tycho code change may be required to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use -Dhttp.proxy.usr=NAME 
Not sure about the name of the password parameter...

Answer (score 0):

Provide the proxy settings including your credentials inside the maven configuration file e.g. /.m2/settings.xml 
Works for Maven 3.3.3 even with NTLM-v2 proxies

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <id>bp</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username>MYUSERNAME</username>
    <password>MYPASSWORD</password>
    <host>my.proxy.host</host>
    <port>808080</port>
    <!--<nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>-->
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```